# Holoviews Dynamic Map with existing Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews

I have a pandas dataframe that I read from a database, with a structure similar to

```
dt  t1  t2 val1 val2
12  A   C  12   33
13  A   B  42   39
14  T   C  12   09
```

and I'm trying to generate a DynamicMap from the dataframe. The problem is that all examples for Dynamic Maps are for generating functions:

```
def gen_values(alpha, beta):
    return np.random.rand()* alpha +  beta

hv.DynamicMap(gen_values, kdims=['alpha', 'beta'])
```

and so on. The problem is that I want to do something similar but with the existing dataframe, and if I try to pass it to the generating function I get an error of missing kdims:

```
def gen_from_pandas(col1, col2, filter_1, filter_2, df):
   df2 = df[(df[col1] == filter_1) & df[col2] == filter2]
   return hv.Curve(df2['dt'], df2['val1'])

hv.DynamicMap(gen_from_pandas, kdims=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply omit ", df" from the argument list of gen_from_pandas, as long as you have defined df before defining that function.  You'll be able to refer to it in the enclosing namespace instead.

ETA: If you can't refer to the enclosing namespace, just make a closure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dt=[12,13,14], t1=['A','A','T'], t2=['C','B','C'], val1=[12,42,12], val2=[33,39,9]))

class fngen(object):
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def __call__(self, column):
        return df[column]

fn = fngen(df)

fn("t1")
```

Comment: That's a problem in the context that I'm working. I cannot rely on the global variable, I would need to pass it to the function. If this is not possible then I cannot use dynamic maps.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain how you propose to pass it to the function; you're wanting to pass it to DynamicMap, and have DynamicMap pass it to the function?

We could support that, but it seems like you could simply use a closure here -- an object that you create that has state but can be called as a function.  See example added above.

Comment: In any case, it would be a lot easier to help with this if there were a runnable example, because as it is it's unclear what would be supplying the values for any of the arguments to the callback function.

Comment: @Ivan: were you able to get this running? Also, @James, I am trying to fix a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703731/chart-pandas-dataframe-columns-using-holoviews-dynamicmap-served-via-flask. I'm passing the df in the callable being passed to DynamicMap, and this df is being re-read each time. I've not been able to understand how to use a closure in my case (i.e. a user will upload a CSV, which the DynamicMap must then visualise) - all the examples on the HV page use the `stocks` dataset that is accessible globally.

Comment: You can use the pattern above for any case like that.  Just create a class, put anything you only want to happen once (including any arguments you only want to provide once) into the `__init__` method, then put the things you want to happen on every update into the `__call__` method.  The instance of this class can then be used as a callable that has its own internal state constructed in `__init__` and available in `__call__`, removing any need for accessing global state.